# Trying to add ECW raster format to geoserver 2.9.3 stores list

Tags: geoserver, ecw

I am trying to add the ECW raster format into geoserver (2.9.3) stores list as a raster data source.

I followed the "http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html" tutorial and i managed to add gdal extension and now i can see more raster data formats but not ecw.

I also tried to follow the installation of ecw sdk from this link:
"https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-ecw"

But i have still an error occuring when starting geoserver :

*ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Pgrogram Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.*

*spec : windows 7 64 bits, java 8 64 bits, MSVC2010, geoserver 2.9.3, imageio-ext 1.1.16, gdal-1.9.2*

Comment: Have you installed the SDK? Make sure you are using the (licensed) Server SDK, not the free Desktop SDK.  Make sure SDK version is > 5.0, not the 4.2 version referred to in the [wiki](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-ecw). What version of GDAL? Installed via OSGeo4W?

Comment: That error message looks like you have a typo: "Pgrogram"

Answer (score 1):

I have just find the solution.
I only put all the *gdal/ecw* (gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll; libecwj2.dll) and *ecw/sdk* (NCSEcw.dll;NCSEcwJNI.dll;NCSEcwJNI_MT.dll) dll files in my Java/bin directory and it works !

Thanks

Pascal